# Problem importing Junit in Eclipse(SpringToolSuite4)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, import, libraries

I'm facing a problem when doing a simple test. I can't understand, since java is installed correctly.

https://postimg.cc/GBB0Ctpx

https://postimg.cc/8sR2DqT9

I was hoping to import the junit library into SpringToolSuite4 but I can't access it.

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type junit cannot be resolved to a module    module-info.java    /ExemploVendasMod25/src/main/java   line 8  Java Problem`

**Description**: The compiler cannot find the junit module.
**Location**: The problem is on line 8 of the module-info.java file.
**Error type**: The compiler is unable to resolve the junit module.

Comment: If you're not planning to use Java modules, remove that `module-info.java` file. If you have to use images, put them in the question rather than linking to elsewhere that may be blocked by firewalls.

Comment: Most probably, in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ JUnit 4 is on the _Classpath_ instead of on the _Modulepath_ causing in `module-info.java` the `requires junit;` not to work. But there are more things odd in your project. You project structure is Maven like, but it is not a Maven project. `src/test/java` is not set up as test sources (using Maven would have avoided this mistake). Consider to delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_), use Maven and upgrade from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5.

Comment: Howler helped me understand the error! Instead of using Junit 4 in "Modulepath" I was using it in Classpath, I just rearranged it and it worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.